# regular expressions in NLTK python

Tags: python, regex, nltk

i have a string in as the following:

```
happy = +2
```

The output should be:

```
JJ[sentiment=+2] -> happy
```

how can regular expression (re) produce something in the format above?

This is my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import nltk
from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize, pos_tag

f = open('file.txt')

for j in iter(f):

    tokens = pos_tag(word_tokenize(j))
    print (tokens)

f.close()
```

The output is:

```
[('happy', 'JJ'), ('2', 'CD')]
```

how can we make it:

```
JJ[sentiment=+2] -> happy
```

best regards

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: You don't need a regex.

Comment: Because I need to stop before the '=' sign, find part of speech (pos) and add [sentiment=value] and then the arrow -> and finally place the word after it. I found the pos, but changing the format of the output is the hard part. so it will look like JJ[sentiment=+2] -> happy instead of [('happy', 'JJ'), ('2', 'CD')]

Comment: You still don't need a regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string formatting and take advantage of tuple indexing.

```
s = [('happy', 'JJ'), ('2', 'CD')]
new = "{0}[sentiment={1}] -> {2}".format(s[0][1], s[1][0], s[0][0]) 
print(new)
JJ[sentiment=2] -> happy
```

Incorporating this into your script now:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import nltk
from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize, pos_tag

f = open('file.txt')

for j in iter(f):

    toks = pos_tag(word_tokenize(j))
    print ("{0}[sentiment={1}] -> {2}".format(toks[0][1], toks[1][0], toks[0][0]))

f.close()
```